# Task :react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I always encounter this error when I try to run my app on an android device. I followed the RNFirebase instruction step by step to add it to my existing project, but it just doesn`t work.

```
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices 
Parsing json file: /Users/myname/Documents/myname/Programmierungen/Project/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/myname/Documents/myname/Programmierungen/Project/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/perf/RNFirebasePerformance.java:50: error: cannot access zzf
    promise.resolve(getOrCreateTrace(identifier).getAttribute(attribute));
                                                ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzf not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
```

It works fine with ios, just compiling for android does not work.

My /app/build.gradle dependencies: (Yes, I did add the apply plugin at the very bottom)

```
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"    
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

The android/build.gradle-dependencies:

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
```

and allprojects:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Other useful information:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
        "react": "16.5.0",
        "react-native": "^0.57.1",
        "react-native-firebase": "^5.0.0"
      },   
    "devDependencies": {
       "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
       "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
       "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
       "jest": "23.6.0",
       "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
       "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
     },
    "jest": {
       "preset": "react-native"
     }
```

I`m coding on macos Mojave with Java 8.
Thanks for helping!! ':D

Comment: i had similar problem , and this helped me: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1155#issuecomment-410886346

Comment: Sry, did not work... I have absolutely no idea where the problem is. I`ve already created a new project and tried to include RNFirebase and it still doesn`t work...